# Expected total principal + gains from a vanguard life cycle account upon retirement after 33 years?

Tags: retirement, roth-ira, investing, lifecycle-fund, yield

If one maxes out his Roth IRA starting from age 26, investing only into a vanguard target 2045 (lifecycle) fund, what amount can he expect to withdraw at retirement at age 59?

I did a quick check using a compound interest calculator: assuming a 5+k contribution is made annually, with 8% interest, the future value turned out to be 930k. How close is this number to the expected number for a lifecycle fund held for 33 years?

Comment: If only we could foretell the future...

Comment: Did you take into account inflation, say on the average of 2-3% a year? I presume when you say "interest" you mean rate-of-return, right? Also, you have to take into account that a lifecycle fund rebalances to less risky investments as it approaches the target date. You could get an estimate of the rebalanced allocation by looking at a fund with a shorter horizon, e.g. [2025](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0304&FundIntExt=INT). It's still *just an estimate*, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have your head in the right space - you seem to be thinking of these lifecycle funds like they're an annuity or a pension, but they're not. They're an investment.

Specifically, they're a mutual fund that will invest in a collection of other mutual funds, which in turn invest in stock and bonds. Stocks go up, and stocks go down. Bonds go up, and bonds go down. How much you'll have in this fund next year is unknowable, much less 32 years from now.

What you can know, is that saving regularly over the next 32 years and investing it in a reasonable, and diversified way in a tax sheltered account like that Roth will mean you have a nice chunk of change sitting there when you retire.

The lifecycle funds exist to help you with that "reasonable" and "diversified" bit.They're meant to be one stop shopping for a retirement portfolio. They put your money into a diversified portfolio, then "age" the portfolio allocations over time to make it go from a high risk, (potentially) high reward allocation now to a lower risk, lower reward portfolio as you approach retirement. The idea is is that you want to shoot for making lots of money now, but when you're older, you want to focus more on keeping the money you have.

Incidentally, kudos for getting into seriously saving for retirement when you're young. One of the biggest positive effects you can have on how much you retire with is simply time. The more time your money can sit there, the better. At 26, if you're putting away 10 percent into a Roth, you're doing just fine. If that 5k is more than 10 percent, you'll do better than fine. (That's a rule of thumb, but it's based on a lot of things I've read where people have gamed out various scenarios, as well as my own, cruder calculations I've done in the past)

Comment: +1 for a very nice answer.  I just edited the answer to insert a missing word in the first sentence of the second paragraph; please delete if you do not agree with the change.

Comment: " If that 5k is more than 10 percent, you'll do better than fine."  Why?  Either way, it's 5k.  I always see % of current earnings touted as what matters, but what matters really is the *quantity of money invested*, whether it is 1% or 99% of your current earnings.  I would much rather invest 1% of a $200k salary than 30% of a $20k salary.

Comment: Your third paragraph removes the sense of risk completely.  You *can't* know you will have a "nice chunk of change sitting there when you retire."  If you could know this, you wouldn't have a full range of risk.

Comment: +1 There really is no way to know what will happen in future years. Additionally, any historical figures you may have read about on the performance of the market in the last few decades should be discounted given that dividend yields (historically roughly have of the total return of the market) have fallen significantly.

Comment: @JAGAnalyst -- exactly. So, what do we know? We know that spending less than you make is good. We know that saving the difference is good. And we know, with somewhat less confidence, that investing those savings prudently and diversely, over the long run, tends to be good.

Comment: @Chelonian -- really? You'd rather only invest $2K on a $200k salary, instead of $6K on a $20K salary?

Comment: @Patches Nope.  It was a typo.  It was supposed to be 10% and 30%.  But in some ways, maybe I *would* prefer it:  I must be living arguably *too* cheaply to invest $6k on a $20k salary, after taxes.  (If I am only saving $2k on a $200k salary, though, I must be living la vida loca.)

Comment: @Chelonian I see. The poster's question was about saving for retirement. Since the goal of saving for retirement is to continue to be able to live in the manner to which you're accustomed, and not in poverty, then the amount you need will be relative to how much you make. In an absolute sense, 5k is 5k. That $930K can produce $37,200 first year, plus inflation subsequent years, indefinitely. So in your example, the CEO making $200K will feel like he's cast into poverty, while the janitor making $20K would retire livin' large. (con't)

Comment: ... The former needs to know he's not saving nearly enough, and the latter needs to know he's doing vary well, and in fact can safely save some of that money for other uses, like a house.

The point here is not absolute numbers or exact forcasting. There is alot that can go wrong over that 32 years; and lot that can go right for that matter. No, the point is to give a 26 year old perspective on what a reasonable amount is to start saving for retirement. A rule of thumb, if you will.

Comment: @Chelonian as for me saying "if you save a decent regularly, and invest it tax-free and sensibly, you will have a nice chunk of change after 32 years" somehow "removing the sense of risk" is nonsense. Even with 0% gains, that's still $160K, which will be useful. There is no 30-year period in the last 100 years where the annualized returns are negative. IIRC, the lowest was 3.5%-4%/year avg. The future is unknown, but you have to game out some pretty apocalyptic scenarios to end up negative. And if such happens you'll have much worse things to worry about than whatever happened to your IRA.

Comment: @Patches I don't buy the first point.  W/ realistic numbers, saving 15% of net is going to leave low-earners vulnerable.  Our example has a janitor saving $5k/yr on ~$18k take-home--it's possible, but that is tight (he has to live on $1,083/mo), and he has to do that every year, year in and year out, getting average 8% ROI the whole time, for 33 years straight.  And that's for a *25%* savings rate on *gross*.  Some of these articles are suggesting a 15% rate on *net*.  I eschew "save enough to live the way you're accustomed" in favor of "earn/save enough to be highly likely to retire strong".

Comment: @Patches Well, either there is a reasonable risk or there isn't.  You're claiming, based on history, there isn't.  That's fine, but then my statement isn't nonsense.  Perhaps you are right:  there is essentially no risk.  And yet, I won't allow myself to believe that:  even with 100+ years of data, you know, "black swans"...

Comment: @Patches And finally, unless I borked the math again, I have the $200k guy saving $20k for 33 years at 8%, having $3.15 million in savings by 59, and drawing $252,000/yr, so he won't feel like he's fallen into poverty.

Comment: @Chelonian and your complaint was that the percentages didn't matter. Which you're now trying to back up by doing math with percentages. All you did was prove my point: which is that 10% is a good rule of thumb on how much to save for retirement.

Comment: @Patches Unrewarding.